# how to publish camera_info manually

Tags: ros, camera-info, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rosbag file which publishes the stereo images (left_image and right_image) but there is no camera_info attached to it.I want use the stereo_image_process package[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) to get the point clouds.This node needs the image as well as camera_info to process the disparity and point cloud.
I have calibrated file in.yaml file format but i don't know how to publish the information in it in a camera info topic for left and right images (camera)

Also,what is the best way to do the above issue with less computation?

Many thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236976/how-to-publish-camera_info-manually/) by [Annaiyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21016/annaiyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on 2016-06-27**:
Hi,
There was a similar post in the ROS forums, check [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/61008/publishing-calibration-data-with-bag-file/) and [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/bag_tools?distro=fuerte#image_sequence_publisher.py) . It might be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nice gist from @rossbar https://gist.github.com/rossbar/ebb282c3b73c41c1404123de6cea4771

```
# Load data from file
with open(yaml_fname, "r") as file_handle:
    calib_data = yaml.load(file_handle)
# Parse
camera_info_msg = CameraInfo()
camera_info_msg.width = calib_data["image_width"]
camera_info_msg.height = calib_data["image_height"]
camera_info_msg.K = calib_data["camera_matrix"]["data"]
camera_info_msg.D = calib_data["distortion_coefficients"]["data"]
camera_info_msg.R = calib_data["rectification_matrix"]["data"]
camera_info_msg.P = calib_data["projection_matrix"]["data"]
camera_info_msg.distortion_model = calib_data["distortion_model"]
return camera_info_msg
```

---

Originally posted by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) with karma: 203 on 2017-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2